# Route Grouping and Namespaces

Tags: laravel, routes, namespaces

i have multiple namespaces in my application namely **FrontEnd** namespace and **BackEnd** namespace, now in my routes file i would like to know the correct way to direct each route to a namespace.

This is what i have at the moment:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'FrontEnd'], function()
{

    Route::group(array('prefix' => '/api/v1/'), function() 
    {

    });


});
```

Now the above works alright (at least when i tried it) but just to make sure i was doing the right thing i wanted to ask so i don't experience and problems in the future.

I would like to know if this is the correct way of going about it instead:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '/api/v1/'), function() 
{
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'FrontEnd'], function()
    {


    });


});
```

Or does it not matter at all whichever way i decide to go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can pass all your option for route group in attribute array like this

```
Route::group(array('middleware' => 'youemiddleware', 'prefix' => 'yourprefixes', 'namespace' => 'yournamespaces', 'domain' => 'subdomains'), function() 
{
// your routes
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I see no preference one over the other.
How about this?

```php
Route::group(array('prefix' => '/api/v1/', 'namespace' => 'FrontEnd'), function() 
{

    // code goes here

});
```